# What is the typical access time for reading a 100KB file over a LAN from an NFSv4

Tags: nfs

Would it be right to compute it as the network time (2ms) + disk seek and block read (10ms) ~= 12ms?
Would that be the correct order of magnitude?

- interested in the response time, not absolute rate.
- Assume mid-range hardware with no caching on (access pattern is too random for caching to help).

Comment: You may want to use a larger file size, 100KB will hardly provide anything worth measuring given 1Gb LAN being a standard these days.

Comment: if you have many files, avoid nfs protocol.

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff I'm interested in the minimal response time for the operation, be it 1 bit of data, or 1MB.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh can you add why? If I have 1 million files stored, made accessible via NFS, and I'm accessing a 10 random ones every second, wouldn't that work fine?

Comment: I think assuming that each side is not overloaded, and assuming the network is not congested, that is a reasonable assumption. It must be tested.

Comment: @GiliNachum Speed of NFS very low.

Comment: @MohsenPahlevanzadeh how slow is very slow (in numbers)?

Comment: @GiliNachum i didn't remember where i read , but when we decide to design our network , NFS rejected by its speed.please google.